# OpenGL: How many black and white (2 tone) images can fit in a single texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, graphics, bit-manipulation

I have 32 black and white images (only two tones, 'on' and 'off').  They are used to represent lighting from different angles, on the same subject.  So they are all the same size and composition.  (The reason it's done this way is because the subject is a 2D character sprite, requiring the lighting be hand drawn)

Is there a way to isolate a single bit (or if not, a single channel) in a 32-bit texture so that OpenGL will draw it by itself, in effect making each texture useable as 32 separate 2-tone images?  (My intent after isolating it is, the black part would be keyed to transparency and the white part is drawn after being modulated)

The reason I want to know is because the sprite sheet for the subjects are all very large (some over 1000x3000 pixels).  There's many sprite sheets for different characters loaded in memory too, in addition to scenery.  I ran a test with 33 textures loaded for every different character type on screen, 1 being the sprite sheet, then 32 lighting sheets, and the program used more than 300MB of video memory.  If it's possible to do this though, I might be able to cut that to a more feasible 30MB range.

Comment: Are you using shaders? Because if you are, this can be accomplished using a relatively simple fragment shader.

Comment: @yzt - I would like to!  But I've held back on them because I'm unsure how many people have cards that support them, and how many wouldn't.

Comment: Since this will be an easy and short shader, you can write it in lower shader models (i.e. lower GLSL versions.) Realistically, you can write this in every GLSL version since 1.10 (or 1.20) which were part of OpenGL version 2.0 (or 2.1). I believe even the cheapest discrete or integrated GPUs made in the past 5-6 years support those versions (and more.)

Comment: I think there might be ways to accomplish what you want (use a packed RGBA8888 texture of bit planes as transparency masks) for the fixed function pipeline. Maybe using a combination of stencil buffer techniques and/or alpha rejection, but I don't know them.

Comment: @yzt - Making a shader is lookin' better knowing that.  I'll try researching after what you mentioned for the fixed pipeline, but if that's too over my head, it's nice to have shaders to fall back on